# Sort depending on member function of the object

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11

I want to sort some `vector` depending on an element's member function value like this:

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> regions;
std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), [](cv::Rect const& l, cv::Rect const& r){
  return l.area() > r.area();
});
```

Can I do it without directly writing the comparison? I can imagine something like:

```
std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), std::compare_greater<cv::Rect::area>);//imaginary code
```

Is there something like this?

**Edit:**
`cv::Rect::area` is a member function that returns `float`. `cv::Rect` does not have a comparison operator or, it has one but I want to sort based on another one.

Comment: Well there is [`std::greater`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/greater) which you can specialize for your type. But if this is just a one-off (and you don't need the `std::greater` specialization for anything else) then a lambda is probably better.

Comment: Do you mean just using the functors from the std library? Aka. C++03 style? There probably is (std::greater, std::men_fn and its ilk), but it will not be neat. A lambda, or custom functor is probably better.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks but is not depending on the existing for comparer operator in the class? I mean can I pass a function (not class) to it?

Comment: @Niall: Thanks. By better you mean readability, performance or what?

Comment: It depends, if you have a comparison operator already for the comparison, and it's a ***non-member*** function then you can just pass it as a pointer to the operator function, like in `std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), operator>)`. But if it's a member function you can't do that (well you *can* but it's much easier to just use a lambda).

Comment: @HumamHelfawi, readability. You probably won't see any improvements or losses in the performance side of things.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg it is member function. Thanks for clarification

Comment: @nial Thanks again but I think I could not explain my problem well. I do not have a compare function and my type is not comparable by operator. I just have a function that return float and I want to compare based on it using a std function that will create the comparer for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following on from the comments on the OP; you can refactor the lambda into its own functor for use the `std::sort`, or you could use a C++03 style by combining the `std::greater`, `std::mem_fun` with a bind (possibly `std::bind`) of some sort etc.; the C++03 style will be cumbersome to work with though.

The functor solution requires the call operator (`operator()`) to have the appropriate signature; accept the required values and return a `bool`, the `const` method and `const&` parameters are not needed, but by convention usually appear.

```
struct compare_rect_greater {
  bool operator()(cv::Rect const& l, cv::Rect const& r) const
  {
    return l.area() > r.area();
  }
};
// ...
std::vector<cv::Rect> regions;
std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), compare_rect_greater());
```

The `float` return from the `area()` function will work as expected with the `operator >`.

But considering the language level, ease of readability etc. your lambda is possible still the better solution.

```
std::vector<cv::Rect> regions;
std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), [](cv::Rect const& l, cv::Rect const& r){
  return l.area() > r.area();
});
```

The C++03 style is unwieldily to create and use in this case, I would not venture too far down this road.

Comment: Thanks. However, I was not seeking something like the first solution I was seeking for std function that will built the first solution for me by itself without writing it by myself. However, it seems not exist. So, your answer fits perfectly

Comment: @HumamHelfawi. There is no "simple" means for this in the std library; I think past the simplest cases, the library was built such that these more complex interactions are moved to their own functor, the variety of combination explode quickly once you start to explore these (taking into account member functions, member variables, pointers, references, `const`, `volatile`, literals...)

Answer (score 3):

You may create a class for that:

```
template <typename Member>
struct greater_member;

template <typename C, typename Method>
class greater_member<Method (C::*)>
{
    explicit greater_member(Method (C::* method)) : mMethod(method) {}

    bool operator()(const C& lhs, const C& rhs) const
    {
        return (lhs.*mMethod)() > (rhs.*mMethod)();
    }

private:
    Method (C::* mMethod);
}

template <typename C, typename Method>
greater_member<Method (C::*)> make_greater_member(Method (C::* method))
{
    return greater_member<Method (C::*)>(method);
}
```

And then

```
std::sort(begin(regions), end(regions), make_greater_member(&cv::Rect::area));
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d1c36bc452591306)

Comment: Nice idea thanks.. I was hoping to find this in the std

Comment: This could be further overengin...err [generalized](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6349c0a8ce861664) in the spirit of cpp-sort's projection facilities :)